# Add a stateful bean using a producer and polymorphism with CDI in JEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, polymorphism, cdi, producer

I'm really new to JEE CDI but tried half of last night to find a solution to a problem.

I have a Controller Class that, when startup is called, should inject a stateful bean using a Producer depending on a parameter. This mentioned stateful bean itself contains an injected bean itself.

To be honest, not sure if this works at all, any feedback is highly appreciated=)

Here is some dummy code that should help understand what I want to do (based oin https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html). Probably I totally messed up a lot of stuff now... but I was not able to find an example how this kind of problem can be solved or I was not able to understand it=/

Controller (main service)

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Controller
{

    private IEngine engine;

    @PostConstruct
    private void startup(int typeID) 
    {
        Factory f = new Factory();
        engine = f.getEngine(typeID)
    }

 }
```

Factory

```
public class Factory
{
    @Produces
    public IEngine getEngine(int typeID) 
    {
        if(typeID==1)
        {
          return new EngineA();
        }    
        else
        {
          return new EngineB();
        }

    }
```

IEngine interface for polymorphism

```
public interface IEngine 
{
    void startUp();
}
```

Here is an Example of EngineA, EngineB is simuliar

```
@Stateful
public class EngineA implements IEngine
{

    @Inject
    private CoinManager cm;

    //@Override
    public void startUp() 
    {
      cm.doSomeThing();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this, even if working, is not allowing me to use @injection in EngineA. In fact, cm in EngineA is null. How can I bring this to work?

BR and THX!
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, let's take a step back and look at it.
Firstly, **do not invoke producers yourself**. Let CDI do the job and just go ahead and tell it where to inject it. Your `Controller` *could* look like this (but it probably won't, there are multiple misunderstanding in your post).

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Controller
{
    @Inject // just tell CDI to give you this
    // it won't be this easy here, but it is just to give you an idea
    private IEngine engine;

}
```

With CDI, you want to **avoid creating instances via `new` when possible**. The reason is, once you yourself create an instance, CDI does *not* have control over creation and hence cannot inject anything into it! This is where your `null` comes from.

Now, if you have a producer...

1) It has to be placed in a bean class (assuming this is OK)

2) Any parameter of producer method has to be injectable

3) Producers usually do create instances via `new`, therefore CDI cannot inject anything in. If you need that, you might want to look into another approach (producers are often used to turn non-CDI objects into bean, therefore they have no need for injection into produced beans).

Your producer has a parameter `int typeID` meaning for CDI to even be able to call and instantiate anything via this method, it needs to have this injectable (for int you would need another producer I imagine). Or, you could place a logic retrieving that `typeID` directly inside producer method instead of passing it as param.

To sum up, the approach you will want to take depends on how and when do you retrieve your `int typeID` and if it can change during runtime. In any case **I would suggest you drop producer method and instead take a look at `Instance<?>` in combination with `@Qualifier`**. That should give you enough versatility and dynamic resolution.