# CDI, polymorphism: Is it possible to inject an implementation of bean B into a bean A based on a field initialized during @PostConstruct of A?

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi

In my JSF application I'm using a `@ViewScoped` bean `Publication` to show/edit data coming from my database. In that bean there is a field for a subtype-specific data object, i.e. containing a different object depending on whether the publication is, say, a book or an article.

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Publication implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    DatabaseStorage storage;

    ...

    String id;
    String type;

    PublicationType typedStuff;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Get an URL parameter from the request,
        // look up row in database accordingly, initialize String "type".
        switch (type) {
        case "ARTICLE":
            typedStuff = new Article(id);
            break;
        case "BOOK":
            typedStuff = new Book(id);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

...with classes `Article` and `Book` that implement / extend `PublicationType`.

So far, so good, but **I would like for `typedStuff` to be a CDI bean, so that I can inject useful resources there.**

I've read [this](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html) page on producer methods, as well as [this tutorial](http://buraktas.com/cdi-dependency-injection-producer-method-example/) and [this very related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423594/add-a-stateful-bean-using-a-producer-and-polymorphism-with-cdi-in-jee), but none of them answer precisely my question: Can I inject based on a field that the injecting bean itself only knows at runtime?

I've gotten the producer method to work as such, but I can't parametrize it, so I can't get that `switch` to work.

- If I put the producer method in a separate class (or bean) then I don't have access to the `type` field.
- If I inject the injecting bean into the producer class, or move the producer method into the injecting class, I get a circular injection.
- If I put the producer method statically into the injecting class, I also don't have access, because `type` cannot be static. (Although, since it's only used momentarily...?)
- Also (and that is probably the answer right there), the producer method is executed before my injecting bean's init method, so `type` wouldn't even have been set yet.

Does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: How do you obtain `type`? Can't you obtain it the same way in the produce method? Also, CDI is lazy, it won't use the producer until you use a bean it produces (well, Weld does that, you might be using OWB and I dunno how it works there). If that scenario fits you, the init of your `@ViewScoped` bean will be over by the type you touch the producer - which means it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot, but you can select a bean based on the field value. Say:

```
public interface PublicationType {}

@PType("ARTICLE")
public class Article implements PublicationType{}

@PType("BOOK")
public class Book implements PublicationType {}
```

And define a qualifier:

```
public @interface PType {
    String value();
}
```

And define an `AnnotationLiteral`:

```
public class PTypeLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<PType> implements PType {}
```

Then you can use:

```
public class Publication {

   @Any
   @Inject
   private Instance<PublicationType> publicationTypes;

   public void doSomething() {
       PType ptype = new PTypeLiteral(type);
       // Of course you will have to handle all the kind of exceptions here.
       PublicationType publicationType = publicationTypes.select(ptype).get();
   }
}
```

Comment: OK, I had to google around a while to find out the missing details of the annotation and the ``AnnotationLiteral``, but I got it to work eventually (though not without Eclipse complaining that I shouldn't use an annotation as a superinterface in the ``implements PType`` bit). It's a quite versatile solution, I like it.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `javax.inject.Provider` interface (I think You are using `@Named` and `@Inject` annotations from the same package).

You could use it to achieve what You want. It will create instances for You with injected fields.

One drawback is that You will have to set the id yourself.

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Publication implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    DatabaseStorage storage;

    @Inject
    Provider<Article> articleProvider;

    @Inject
    Provider<Book> bookProvider;

    String id;
    String type;

    PublicationType typedStuff;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Get an URL parameter from the request,
        // look up row in database accordingly, initialize String "type".
        switch (type) {
        case "ARTICLE":
            typedStuff = articleProvider.get();
            typedStuff.setId(id);
            break;
        case "BOOK":
            typedStuff = bookProvider.get();
            typedStuff.setId(id);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the id myself would not be a problem. I could easily switch the constructor for an init method called after construction. I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Antares Please take a look at the fixes in my answer, because I wrote earlier that Provider is an annotation, when in reality it is an interface.

Comment: Yeah, I went right into that trap, thanks for your correction. With everything set up like you said, things work flawlessly. It's going to be a lot of providers, though, because in the real world I will have about a dozen (or more) subtypes. I'm going to have a look at @maress's answer as well.